# Page not found (404) error happens I did not write the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I got an error,Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    `http://localhost:8000/app/test.html?prop=value` .
I wrote `index.html` like

```
<body>
　  <form method="post" action="">
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

    {% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id=type{{forloop.counter}}>
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();
              for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            }).trigger('change');

        });


  </script>

     <form id="postform" action="http://localhost:8000/app/test_view" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="SEND">
     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        let key = "prop";
        let value = "value";
        var array1 = [];
        var array2 =[];
          document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
           const test = window.open(`test.html?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
          }

     </script>
  </body>
```

This part `const test = window.open('test.html?${key}=${value}', "_blank");` causes error because I did not regist url `http://localhost:8000/app/test.html?prop=value`. I only register `http://localhost:8000/app/test_view`. But I wanna send selected i & value's values to test.html,so I wrote this like.
I wrote in `test.html` like

```
<body>

<h2>RESULT</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      onload = () => {
        document.body.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode([...new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()])
          );
      }

    </script>

</body>
```

How should I fix this?What should I write this?

`urls.py` is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^test_view$', views.test_view, name='test_view'),
]
```

views.py is

```
def test_view(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

My app structure is
testapp(parent app)
  -app(child app)
    -inde.html&test.html&views.py

testapp's `urls.py` is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

Now my code is

```
<form id="postform" action="http://localhost:8000/app/test_view" method="GET">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <a href={% url 'test_view' %}>Your link to test view</a>
     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        let key = "prop";
        let value = "value";
        var array1 = [];
        var array2 =[];
          document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
           const test = window.open(`test.html?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
          }

     </script>
```

Comment: Show your `urls.py` file from project dorectory, where you include `urls.py` for your application. Because for now(what i can see) is that you register only `localhost:8000/test_view`

Comment: Where is your /app/ mounted?

Comment: I added testapp(parent app)'s urls.py.If u know something, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registred `http://localhost:8000/app/test_html` but try to go by `http://localhost:8000/app/test.html` link. Your `GET` parameters don't make a sense.

You should use url, that you registred in `urls.py`.
Read this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/) about views and urls.

Change `action` attribute in your form. It might looks like that:

In your template your link may looks like this:

```
<form id="postform" action="{% url 'test_view' %}" method="GET">
```

or:

```
<form id="postform" action="app/test_view" method="GET">
```

Instead of:

```
<form id="postform" action="http://localhost:8000/app/test_view" method="POST">
```

This is because in `action` or another place where you add your url, when you develop in local machine you should write url path without domain:
`app/test_view` instead of `http://localhost:8000/app/test_view`

Comment: thx,ur comments.I wanna access http://localhost:8000/app/test_view?prop=value  when I  put `<input type="submit" value="SEND">` button so what should I write it?

Comment: @user8681386, why do you want use `input` try to use `a` tag. 
`<a href={% url  'test_view' %}>Your link to test view</a>`

Comment: I added my question in last part Now my code is ~~.Is it ur intended codes?

Comment: @user8681386, I write this in my answer